# Disable Advertising ID (AAID) collection runtime in Unity Firebase SDK

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

[image: screenshot]

The new Google policy requires app to not transmit Android Advertising ID when targeting for both children and adults. Is there any option that we can disable it in runtime based on user preference? I found only this doc about disabling the AAID permanently using meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=android. I'm currently using Unity Firebase SDK at the moment and it does not seem like there's an option for it nor Android native Firebase SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this used in Firebase unity sample [MechaHamster](https://github.com/google/mechahamster) in [Startup.cs](https://github.com/google/mechahamster/blob/9ee186dfe48a35bb4e26369a78e8c350942098c3/Assets/Hamster/Scripts/States/Startup.cs) file, here how they used it:

```
 // Start gathering analytic data.
    void InitializeAnalytics() {
      Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

      // Set the user's sign up method.
      Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserProperty(
        Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.UserPropertySignUpMethod,
        "Google");

      if (CommonData.currentUser != null)
        Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserId(CommonData.currentUser.data.id);
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid disabling entire Analytics? It seems like there an option to just disable AAID without turning off Analytics, but that's permanent and only available in native Android.

Comment: You can [Exclude specific events and user-scoped custom dimensions from ads personalization](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9494752)

Comment: Can we do this in runtime? As mentioned in the desc, I'm looking for a way to disable AAID in runtime based on user preference.

Comment: I don't think so. But you can create custom dimension or new events just for users who disable this, and make these dimensions or events excluded from ads personalization

Comment: That's a good workaround, though I still hope Firebase would provide an official way to do that =(

Comment: @kkl was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?